# Swift 2.0 String to NSDate

Tags: string, swift, firebase, nsdate

Hello i get my date from Datepicker that gets saved to a string then uploaded to Firebase. The string is then recieved to the phone. The problem is that i want to convert this string to NSDate when i retrieve it.

This is how i get a string from datepicker

```
func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker){
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strDateFrom = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    fromDate = strDateFrom
    print(fromDate)}
```

When i retrieve the date i get it as a string this is the print

```
print(self.membershipActiveTo)
```

And this is the print log 
  5/11/16, 2:35 PM

And below is the line of code i have tried to convert to string but it only returns nil

```
let strDate = self.membershipActiveTo // "2015-10-06T15:42:34Z"
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
        print ( dateFormatter.dateFromString( strDate ) )
```

Comment: The line of text in the bottom is supposed to be: And below is the line of code i have tried to convert toNSDate but it only returns nil

Comment: The string "2015-10-06T15:42:34Z" does *not* match the date format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" ...

Comment: So how should i write it then? "MM-dd-YY"

Comment: for `"2015-10-06T15:42:34Z"` the date formatter is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`; it was not really hard, I guess.

Comment: I guess i have asked the question wrong my problem is that i want to convert this string 5/11/16, 2:35 PM to a NSDate so i can compare it with another date

Comment: The answer is the same: Lookup the documentation and find the matching date format. – Note however, that "5/11/16, 2:35 PM" is a *bad* format to store a date on a server: Locale dependent (AM/PM or 24 hours), years truncated to 2 digits, time zone dependent, ... Better use a standard format like ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things to consider when working with dates and one of them is how to store the date in a consistent format that can be easily worked with for different uses. In your case, you may want to sort by date and if the data is stored like this

5/11/16, 2:35 PM

It's not going to be sortable. So, a different format is needed and here's one possible example

```
20160511143500
```

Here's some code to manipulate dates:

Write a nicely formatted date to Firebase

```
let d = NSDate()

//create a custom date string & save in firebase
let dateFormatterCustom = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatterCustom.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddhhmmss"

let customDateString = dateFormatterCustom.stringFromDate(d)
print(customDateString) //prints "20160511023500" just for testing

let timesRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("time_test")
let thisTimeRef = timesRef.childByAutoId()
let timeChildRef = thisTimeRef.childByAppendingPath("timestamp")

timeChildRef.setValue(customDateString)
```

Firebase now has this

```
time_test  
 -KFerAcANQv4pN1Pp4yW
    timestamp: "20160418033309"
```

Then to read in from Firebase:

```
    let timesRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("time_test")

    timesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let timeStamp = snapshot.value.objectForKey("timestamp") as! String
        print(timeStamp) //still looks like 20160418033309

        let shortDateString = self.timeStampToDateString(timeStamp)
        print(shortDateString) //prints 4/18/16, 3:33 AM

    })
```

and the function that converts the timestamp style string to a human readable one

```
func timeStampToDateString(stamp: String) -> String {

    //create a custom date string & create a date object from it
    let dateFormatterCustom = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatterCustom.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "US_en")
    dateFormatterCustom.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddhhmmss"

    let d = dateFormatterCustom.dateFromString(stamp)!

    //create a short date style string and format the string
    let dateFormatterShortStyle  = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatterShortStyle.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatterShortStyle.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    let dateString = dateFormatterShortStyle.stringFromDate(d)

    return dateString
}
```

There's a lot of extra code in this example so it could be shortened considerably but I wanted to leave in all of the steps.

Comment: Thanks alot! I used the code that u showed at the start of your comment i guess my format was wrong :)